# Impossible to use WebStorm with React + MUI

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, material-ui, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 2022 with React, JavaScript and MUI -- and I have been getting insanely slow performance, that it's become impossible to use.

Autocomplete takes around 6-7 seconds to load, and my CPU usage rockets up to 100% whenever I type anything in my JSX file.

Example code:

```
function UserInputBox() {
    return (
        <Box
            display="flex"
            flexDirection="column"

            alignItems="center" p={5} boxShadow={3}
        >
            <Box
                p={5}
                sx={{background: "blue", alignItems: "stretch"}}
            >
                <h1>User Input</h1>
            </Box>

            <Stack spacing={2}>
                <TextField label="Username" />
                <TextField label="Age (Years)" />
                <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    sx={{borderRadius: 28, textTransform: "none"}}
                >
                    Add User
                </Button>
            </Stack>
        </Box>
    )
}

export default UserInputBox
```

Comment: Performance issues quite often are rather machine or project specific (i.e. the same project can perform just fine on another machine). The best way is to contact JetBrains Support where you can privately provide all the required info. Easiest way: `WebStorm Main Menu | Help | Contact Support...` and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: What operating system are you on? If you are on Linux then you could create a virtual machine (e.g. via VirtualBox) and try it in a completely fresh environment. Perhaps there's some WebStorm caches that have become corrupted or stale.

Comment: I'm having the same issues with MUI and PhpStorm.  `Plugin JavaScript and TypeScript: lang.javascript.psi.types (in com.intellij)` seems to be the culprit, but I can't seem to find a way to solve it. You can see the CPU spike in the activity monitor.

Comment: @Pistachio yeah, it's an issue. I switched to ChakraUI because of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was due to the bug in webstorm. They had fixed it and will probably comes in the next EAP build. Check below link for activity.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-59766/Very-slow-code-analysis-in-React-MUI-Javascript-code

Comment: haven't verified (I use VSCode now) but thanks, hopefully it's been addressed

Comment: Yes i am also using vscode for now. But hopefully next EAP build will come on next tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my mac. The solution is to simply [install version](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/other.html) 2022.2 instead of 2022.3

Comment: does not fix it